# AppEngine abnormal instance warm ups java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

in the last 2 days we are experiencing instance warmups every minute or so. The instance comes up, and shuts down right away.
We didn't change anything in the last week, and it suddenly started to happen.
We increased the residents amount for now but the system still appears to spawn dynamic instances abnormally.

We also see that cool warm up times increased from 11 seconds to 47 seconds in avg. without any significant change to the code.

How can we best peruse this issue? Does anyone experience a similar behavior from the last couple of days?

Took this screen capture several hours ago
[image: Loading latency graph depicting the problem]

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here, there are AppEngine community forums and even an IRC channel: https://developers.google.com/appengine/community You could also try one of those.

Comment: I met this problem too, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764245/gae-keep-starting-new-processes-at-every-request

Comment: Same here. Even stranger than this - I started getting very bad results in my production environment, however my QA environment still works perfectly - With exactly the same codebase and configuration.

Comment: Same here, and i'm getting over quota(never happen before) for two days, did you file any bug to GAE team so we can star?

Comment: I didn't know I can open issues for appengine, We registered for the silver support package to get some support, though so far nothing.

Comment: Hi, How about the situation about your problem now? did you finally get support from google? sadly i found an existing bug about this issue and it last nearly two years, no feedback from google side in the issue tracker.

Comment: Shuky -- the issue tracker is here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/FilingIssues?tm=3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We received a response from google's support team.
Apparently, there was a problem with the physical server our application was hosted on.
We had to pay for silver support and wait around 3 days to get that answer...

If you are experiencing the same, I would suggest contacting their support.