# GAE keep starting new processes at nearly every request

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I met a very rare situation today that my GAE project keep starting a new processes even when `every` request coming, this is really weird, from the server log, it give me below warning so many times in just one minute:

```
    This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused 
    your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take
    longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
```

As the starting of a new process takes 3-4 seconds, so the result is really bad, so much latency. I have another project with more traffic than this one but no such issue. Anyone who can tell me what's the cause of this nasty problem and how to solve this? Many thanks.
[image]

Comment: AFAIK, GAE used to *always* do this, so this is an improvement that it only does this some of the time.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763516/appengine-abnormal-instance-warm-ups-java

Comment: Thanks for the reply, every request took about 4 seconds to response, and every now and then there is DeadLineException thrown and the app is totally unusable, i don't think this is...normal.

Comment: If you see the link someone else appears to have seen a change this week in the behaviour.

Comment: What latencies were you getting last week?

Comment: Thanks Peter, my app run normally for more than one month without any change.

Comment: Sounds like they changed the behaviour of the system.  I would contact google support to see if they can change it back.

Comment: I update the picture. seem things did not recovered till now, and we are over quota in two days(we'r billing user), which never occur in a few months, too bad impact to our business and our customers.